# In Blazor, is there any way to get render time for any component without its children?

Tags: blazor

Because there seems to be [no way to profile rendering](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/26850) slowness in Blazor, I've seen a need to get some kind of info about render timings.

In any Blazor component, I can get render time for any component like so:

```cs
private Stopwatch? RenderTimer { get; set; } = null;
protected override void OnInitialized() => RenderTimer = Stopwatch.StartNew();

protected override bool ShouldRender()
{
    RenderTimer = Stopwatch.StartNew(); // all re-renders (not the first render)
    return true;
}

protected override void OnAfterRender(bool firstRender)
{
    if (RenderTimer == null) return;
    RenderTimer.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine($"{(int)RenderTimer.ElapsedMilliseconds} ms to render {GetType().Name}");
}
```

But such a render time can include any or all of its subcomponents, because of course rendering a component might include rendering all its subcomponents.

Can you think of any way I can `Stop` the stopwatch before rendering each subcomponent and then start it again once back to rendering the content of this component-proper?

Comment: The straight answer is no.  The time it takes to render a component isn't directly related to the time it takes to render sub-components.  On first render there is a relationship that you could probably inaccurately time, but beyond that it all depends on what's changing and to who.  Your question suggests you have a rendering issue?

Comment: I would add that it is very rare for rendering a component to be slow unless it has thousands of children - much more common is unwanted/unnecessary re-rendering caused by `EventCallback`s in binding to child components. Timing between `ShouldRender` and `OnAfterRender` is useful, but also add counter to see if you have too many renders.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis - when the subs have a non-trivial parameter they will always 'Render', ie rebuild their shadow DOM. That may or may not lead to updates in the actual DOM. So I partially agree with you.

Comment: Mister Magoo, I agree for one component.  But some user actions cause thousands of components to re-render, and I want to aggregate the timings for them.  (The code above is simplified for purposes of keeping this question narrow.)

Comment: Henk, both.  I'd like to see where my delays are in hopes of narrowing what to try to optimize.  If this works, I'll probably add code to distinguish between OnParameterChange and other methods.

Answer (score 3):

There are two distinct processes going on in a component:

#### State Change

The following processes modify the component state:

1. The lifecyle events - `OnInitialized{Async}/OnParametersSet{Async}`.
2. UI Events registered in the component.
3. Externally hooked up events.
4. Direct calls by parent components to public methods.

`ComponentBase` manages the first two of these and *requests* one or more component renders by calling `StateHasChanged`.

You need to manually call `StateHasChanged` in the last two to request a component render.

#### Render

The call to `StateHasChanged` only places a `RenderFragment` on the Renderer's RenderQueue.  It doesn't in itself cause a render.  The renderer will run the render fragment when it gets thread time on the UI thread.

### BlazorComponentBase

The component below is a *black box* equivalent version of `ComponentBase` with some timers and debug printing for the following:

1. The `OnInitialized{Async}/OnParametersSet{Async}` lifecycle process.
2. UI Events.
3. The Render process run by the Renderer.

There are some important caveats to understand:

1. Taking the measurements affects the timings.
2. In any async process we're measuring the start to end time, not the actual execution time.  Any yielding process may get "blocked" by another process and appear to take a long time.

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;
using System.Diagnostics;

public abstract class BlazorComponentBase : IComponent, IHandleEvent, IHandleAfterRender
{
    protected RenderFragment componentRenderFragment;
    private RenderHandle _renderHandle;
    protected bool initialized;
    protected bool hasNeverRendered = true;
    protected bool hasPendingQueuedRender;
    private bool _hasCalledOnAfterRender;

    protected virtual string ComponentName => this.GetType().Name;

    public BlazorComponentBase()
    {
        componentRenderFragment = builder =>
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"{this.ComponentName} UI started a render at {GetTime()}");
            var timer = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            hasPendingQueuedRender = false;
            hasNeverRendered = false;
            BuildComponent(builder);
            Debug.WriteLine($"{this.ComponentName} rendered in {timer.Elapsed}");
        };
    }

    protected virtual void BuildComponent(RenderTreeBuilder builder)
        => BuildRenderTree(builder);

    protected virtual void BuildRenderTree(RenderTreeBuilder builder) { }

    protected virtual void OnInitialized() { }

    protected virtual Task OnInitializedAsync() => Task.CompletedTask;

    protected virtual void OnParametersSet() { }

    protected virtual Task OnParametersSetAsync() => Task.CompletedTask;

    protected void StateHasChanged()
        => _renderHandle.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(Render);

    internal protected void Render()
    {
        if (hasPendingQueuedRender)
            return;

        if (hasNeverRendered || ShouldRender() || _renderHandle.IsRenderingOnMetadataUpdate)
        {
            hasPendingQueuedRender = true;

            try
            {
                _renderHandle.Render(componentRenderFragment);
            }
            catch
            {
                hasPendingQueuedRender = false;
                throw;
            }
        }
    }

    protected virtual bool ShouldRender() => true;

    protected virtual void OnAfterRender(bool firstRender) { }

    protected virtual Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender) => Task.CompletedTask;

    protected Task InvokeAsync(Action workItem)
        => _renderHandle.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(workItem);

    protected Task InvokeAsync(Func<Task> workItem)
        => _renderHandle.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(workItem);

    void IComponent.Attach(RenderHandle renderHandle)
    {
        if (_renderHandle.IsInitialized)
            throw new InvalidOperationException($"The render handle is already set. Cannot initialize a {nameof(ComponentBase)} more than once.");

        _renderHandle = renderHandle;
    }

    public virtual async Task SetParametersAsync(ParameterView parameters)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"{this.ComponentName} UI started a lifecycle at {GetTime()}");
        var timer = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        parameters.SetParameterProperties(this);

        if (!initialized)
        {
            initialized = true;

            await this.RunInitAndSetParametersAsync();
        }
        else
            await this.CallOnParametersSetAsync();

        Debug.WriteLine($"{this.ComponentName} lifefcyled in {timer.Elapsed}");
    }

    private async Task RunInitAndSetParametersAsync()
    {
        this.OnInitialized();

        var task = this.OnInitializedAsync();

        if (task.Status != TaskStatus.RanToCompletion && task.Status != TaskStatus.Canceled)
        {
            this.Render();

            try
            {
                await task;
            }
            catch // avoiding exception filters for AOT runtime support
            {
                if (!task.IsCanceled)
                    throw;
            }
        }

        await this.CallOnParametersSetAsync();
    }

    private Task CallOnParametersSetAsync()
    {
        this.OnParametersSet();

        var task = this.OnParametersSetAsync();
        var shouldAwaitTask = task.Status != TaskStatus.RanToCompletion &&
            task.Status != TaskStatus.Canceled;

        Render();

        return shouldAwaitTask ?
            this.CallStateHasChangedOnAsyncCompletion(task) :
            Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    private async Task CallStateHasChangedOnAsyncCompletion(Task task)
    {
        try
        {
            await task;
        }
        catch
        {
            if (task.IsCanceled)
                return;

            throw;
        }
        Render();
    }

    async Task IHandleEvent.HandleEventAsync(EventCallbackWorkItem callback, object? arg)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"{this.ComponentName} UI started an event at {GetTime()}");
        var timer = Stopwatch.StartNew();

        var task = callback.InvokeAsync(arg);
        var shouldAwaitTask = task.Status != TaskStatus.RanToCompletion && task.Status != TaskStatus.Canceled;

        Render();

        if (shouldAwaitTask)
            await this.CallStateHasChangedOnAsyncCompletion(task);

        Debug.WriteLine($"{this.ComponentName} UI evented in {timer.Elapsed}");
    }

    Task IHandleAfterRender.OnAfterRenderAsync()
    {
        var firstRender = !_hasCalledOnAfterRender;
        _hasCalledOnAfterRender |= true;

        OnAfterRender(firstRender);

        return this.OnAfterRenderAsync(firstRender);
    }

    private string GetTime()
    {
        Math.DivRem(DateTime.Now.Ticks, TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond, out long millisecondparts);
        var mills = DateTime.Now.Ticks / TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond;
        Math.DivRem(mills, 1000, out long millseconds);
        return $" {DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()}:{millseconds}:{millisecondparts}";
    }
}
```

Here's a set of results from the standard Blazor template.

```
// F5 on Index
App UI started a lifecycle at  16:10:19:465:2698
App UI started a render at  16:10:19:468:3597
App rendered in 00:00:00.0001903
NavMenu UI started a lifecycle at  16:10:19:475:9989
NavMenu lifefcyled in 00:00:00.0000164
Index UI started a lifecycle at  16:10:19:480:766
Index lifefcyled in 00:00:00.0000205
NavMenu UI started a render at  16:10:19:486:1515
NavMenu rendered in 00:00:00.0000303
Index UI started a render at  16:10:19:491:4845
Index rendered in 00:00:00.0000197
SurveyPrompt UI started a lifecycle at  16:10:19:498:1386
SurveyPrompt lifefcyled in 00:00:00.0000244
SurveyPrompt UI started a render at  16:10:19:503:8187
SurveyPrompt rendered in 00:00:00.0000147
App lifefcyled in 00:00:00.0420088
...
//changed to the FetchData page
NavMenu UI started an event at  16:11:08:611:4731
NavMenu UI evented in 00:00:00.0003278
NavMenu UI started a render at  16:11:08:617:61
NavMenu rendered in 00:00:00.0000705
FetchData UI started a lifecycle at  16:11:08:633:7379
FetchData lifefcyled in 00:00:00.0031458
FetchData UI started a render at  16:11:08:641:7874
FetchData rendered in 00:00:00.0010507
....
// Changed to the Counter page
NavMenu UI started an event at  16:11:10:612:2966
NavMenu UI evented in 00:00:00.0000210
NavMenu UI started a render at  16:11:10:616:7572
NavMenu rendered in 00:00:00.0000292
Counter UI started a lifecycle at  16:11:10:622:4540
Counter lifefcyled in 00:00:00.0002307
Counter UI started a render at  16:11:10:628:9948
Counter rendered in 00:00:00.0008271
.....
// Clicked the increment button
Counter UI started an event at  16:11:12:53:9117
Counter UI evented in 00:00:00.0003249
Counter UI started a render at  16:11:12:66:2064
Counter rendered in 00:00:00.0000431
```

Answer (score 2):

This answer is intended to be controversial as this is an immensely complex topic.

Most of the code in most components is never run, and most of the renders that occur due to Ui events result in no UI updates.

The world doesn't begin and end with `ComponentBase`, though it may be a little hard to believe.

```cs
public class RadzenComponent : ComponentBase, IDisposable
```

```cs
public abstract class MudComponentBase : ComponentBase
```

> Most of the developer-facing component lifecycle concepts are encapsulated in this base class. The core components rendering system doesn't know about them (it only knows about IComponent). This gives us flexibility to change the lifecycle concepts easily, or for developers to design their own lifecycles as different base classes.

This is the comment at the top of the `ComponentBase` code.  I don't think MS ever dreamed `ComponentBase` would become another Google!

Consider this implementation:

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;

namespace Blazr.Components;
public abstract class LeanComponentBase : IComponent
{
    protected RenderFragment renderFragment;
    private RenderHandle _renderHandle;
    protected bool initialized;
    private bool _hasNeverRendered = true;
    private bool _hasPendingQueuedRender;

    [Parameter] public Boolean Hidden { get; set; } = false;

    public LeanComponentBase()
    {
        this.renderFragment = builder =>
        {
            if (!this.Hidden)
            {
                _hasPendingQueuedRender = false;
                _hasNeverRendered = false;
                this.BuildRenderTree(builder);
            }
        };
    }

    void IComponent.Attach(RenderHandle renderHandle)
        => _renderHandle = renderHandle;

    public virtual async Task SetParametersAsync(ParameterView parameters)
    {
        parameters.SetParameterProperties(this);
        var shouldRender = this.ShouldRenderOnParameterChange(initialized);

        if (_hasNeverRendered || shouldRender)
        {
            await this.OnParameterChangeAsync(!initialized);
            this.Render();
        }

        this.initialized = true;
    }

    protected virtual void BuildRenderTree(RenderTreeBuilder builder) { }

    protected virtual ValueTask OnParameterChangeAsync(bool firstRender)
        => ValueTask.CompletedTask;

    protected virtual bool ShouldRenderOnParameterChange(bool initialized)
        => true;

    protected void Render()
    {
        if (_hasPendingQueuedRender)
            return;

        _hasPendingQueuedRender = true;
        _renderHandle.Render(renderFragment);
    }

    protected void StateHasChanged()
        => _renderHandle.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(Render);
}
```

You:

1. Can take control of whether a parameter update caused a render cascade.
2. You control rendering on UI events.
3. There's one lifecycle event.

Comment: Interesting. The actual answer would be to surround  `this.BuildRenderTree(builder)` with some Stopwatch code.  Much cleaner than what I did.  But it doesn't offer much more grip on the relation with the subcomponents, as far as I can see.

Comment: @HenkHolterman - Personally I don't think clicking the stopwatch is the answer.  The first line of Patrick's question says "no way to profile rendering slowness in Blazor".  Slowness suggests slow UI response which suggests either a design issue or blocking code.  He could be using SQLLite on a slow connection with pseudo async code for all we know!

Comment: I'll try these soon.  I believe I have slowness in rendering many components.  Just not sure where the bottlenecks are.  I am quite sure it is not due to API/database calls.  Thanks for the ideas.

Comment: @PatrickSzalapski - Check that your DB/API calls are REALLY async, and whatever data pipeline you're using does yield back to the UI.

Comment: Good advice.   For the above, I assume I need to inherit from this new LeanComponentBase in every component that I want to gather info from?  Is there any way to inject the default base component?

Comment: @PatrickSzalapski - Having thought about this, I've added a new answer to show you how you can do some timings using an equivalent `black box` `ComponentBase` base component.   On `LeanComponentBase`, this answer was as I suggested at the top to challenge and show that there's more to the Blazor UI than `ComponentBase`.  And No there's no way to blanket replace.  I have several different base components (horses for courses), and now always state the inheritance at the top of a component.