# Difference between MudBlazor's paper and element

Tags: blazor, mudblazor

Mudblazor has two concepts for a div-like tag: [`MudElement`](https://mudblazor.com/components/element) and [`MudPaper`](https://mudblazor.com/components/paper). (They differ to other enclosing elements, like a `MudContainer` or `MudGrid`/`MudItem`, which are used for layout.)

Many examples use one or the other almost exclusively, so it seems like a personal choice. They seem very similar to me.

Are they just blazor representations of a `<div>`? When would I use one or the other?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`MudPaper` is `div` with formatting.

It's Razor looks like this:

```cs
@inherits MudComponentBase;

<div @attributes="UserAttributes" class="@Classname" style="@Stylename">
    @ChildContent
</div>
```

You can see the code here:
https://github.com/MudBlazor/MudBlazor/blob/dev/src/MudBlazor/Components/Paper/MudPaper.razor
https://github.com/MudBlazor/MudBlazor/blob/dev/src/MudBlazor/Components/Paper/MudPaper.razor.cs

`MudElement` is a more versatile component.  By default it's a `span`, but it can be whatever you want to set it to.  It uses `RenderTreeBuilder` methods to build out the html code, so I won't regurgitate the code here.  You can see it here: https://github.com/MudBlazor/MudBlazor/blob/dev/src/MudBlazor/Components/Element/MudElement.cs

Comment: Thanks. So is there no guidance for when to use one or the other? Seems the element is more useful, but because it's a span they added a div, as a "short-cut" for when you need a div. If that's all, the names MudSpan and MudDiv would have been less confusing... :-)

Comment: I think it's use what's most appropriate.  MudBlazor call MudElement a "primitive component" which you can use as a base for your own components.   I don't use MudBlazor or any other component library.  I'm not a fan of using `ComponentBase` carte-blanche: almost every library's base-base component is `ComponentBase`.  It's a bloated piece of code that eats memory and CPU cycles.  And thanks.

Comment: Now I'm really intrigued - are you saying that I can create components without subclassing `ComponentBase`? (Also, I'm surprised to hear it's inefficient, I'll keep that in mind.)

Comment: See my first answer to this question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73717873/in-blazor-is-there-any-way-to-get-render-time-for-any-component-without-its-chi/73788324#73788324.  Consider `MudPaper`.  It has a `RenderFragment` Parameter defined so renders every time it's parent renders - A renderfragment is an object so the Renderer can't detect if it has/hasn't changed and takes the safe option.  All the lifecycle stuff gets called with Tasks constructed to do nothing.  And the Renderer has to manage and handle the after render cycle though it doesn't do anything.

Comment: Every component's footprint contains all this code: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Components/Components/src/ComponentBase.cs.  Consider how much of it gets used in `MudPaper`.  Consider presenting `MudPaper` for code review if you put all the `ComponentBase` code directly into the class.